# Testing a jpql query with junit and mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, hibernate-entitymanager

Can someone please help me with writing a unit test case for a jpql query? I am new to this.

This is the class to be tested.

```
@Inject
private Log log;

@PersistenceContext(name = Configuration.PERSISTENT_CONTEXT)
private EntityManager em;

 public List<Vehicle> getData() {
    List<Vehicle> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT v FROM Vehicle v JOIN v.car c WHERE c.carType = 'BMW'";
        Query query = em.createQuery(sql, Vehicle.class);
        resultList = query.getResultList();

        if(resultList == null){
            log.error("List is empty or null");
            return null;
        }

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        log.info(ex.getMessage());
        log.trace(ex.getCause());
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

The JUnit class that I have written so far is as follows:

```
@InjectMocks
private FinderManager classUnderTest;

@Mock
private EntityManager emMock;

@Mock
private Query query;

@Mock
private Vehicle vehicle;

@Mock
private Car car;

@Test
public void testMethod(){
     List<Vehicle> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

    Mockito.when(emMock.createQuery(Mockito.any(String.class)))
    .thenReturn(query);

    Mockito.when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(resultList);

    classUnderTest.getData();

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@Mock
private EntityManager em;

@Mock
private Vehicle vehicle;

@Mock
private Car car;

@Mock
private Query query;

@InjectMocks
private YourDAOClass yourDAOClass;

@Test
public void testMethod(){
     List<Vehicle> someList = null;


    when(em.createQuery(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(query);


    when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(someList);

    assertThat(yourDAOClass.getData()).isNull()

}
```

Comment: When I debug the test method, it returns a null query in the getData() method. I have edited the test class above.

Comment: it gives a NullPointerException @Shaunak

Comment: It should not. Let me try on my system

Comment: Yes please! I am trying to fix this since so long! @Shaunak

Comment: Updated. This code I've tested on my system and its working as expected.